# How can I define a function to accept all the types which extend a common base type (Scala, specific code below)?

Tags: scala

I am having a problem defining my types correctly in the code block below.

What I am trying to do:
I am trying to define a general function called `processMyFuncResult` which takes the result of another function (the worker function), a function to be invoked in the event of a successful computation, and a function to be invoked upon failure. My intent is to have many different types of worker functions of which the results are variable in content, but should extend the trait `MyFuncResult[T]`.

The problem:

In the code below, I am generating a compilation error and after much struggling with this cannot seem to get to a working solution where I can pass the specific subtypes for context and result into the OnSuccess and OnFailure Functions.

I have tried introducing new type params to the result processing function and messing around with the bounds and variances, the former which has the effect of pushing the same problem to the body of the `processMyFuncResult`, and the latter which seems to have no effect, but I have exhausted my tweaking to no avail.

Compilation Error:

```
Error:(37, 41) type mismatch;
found   : (Int, WorkerContext) => Unit
required: (?, MyFuncContext) => Unit
processMyFuncResult(exampleComputation, printWorkerSuccess, printWorkerFailure)

Error:(37, 61) type mismatch;
found   : (CouldntDoitError, WorkerContext) => Unit
required: (MyError, MyFuncContext) => Unit
processMyFuncResult(exampleComputation, printWorkerSuccess, printWorkerFailure)
```

Code:

```scala
// ErrorTypes
trait MyError
case class CouldntDoitError(msg: String) extends MyError

// Context for passing more information to post-processing function
trait MyFuncContext
case class WorkerContext(passedArg: Int) extends MyFuncContext

// Traits / Types for Worker func results - all workers should return this kind of result
trait WorkerFuncResult[T] {
  def result: Either[MyError, T]
  def context: MyFuncContext
}

case class WorkerResult(result: Either[MyError, Int], context: MyFuncContext) extends WorkerFuncResult[Int]

// Processing function which does the interesting work and returns a WorkerFuncResult
// There are many of these which have specific types which they return (e.g. WorkerResult)
def workerFunc(a: Int): WorkerResult = {
  val compRes = for {
                  res1 <- if (a < 10) Left(CouldntDoitError("Less than 10 ")) else Right(a * 2)
                  res2 <- if (a < 30) Left(CouldntDoitError("almost made it but didn't")) else Right(res1 * 100)
                } yield res2

  WorkerResult(compRes, WorkerContext(a))
}

// Post-processing function - takes a result and invokes an on success function or on failure function 
// On the appropriate result or error
def processMyFuncResult[T](computationResult: WorkerFuncResult[T],
                           onSuccess: (T, MyFuncContext) => Unit,
                           onFailure: (MyError, MyFuncContext) => Unit) =
  computationResult.result match {
    case Right(v) => onSuccess(v, computationResult.context)
    case Left(e) => onFailure(e, computationResult.context)
  }


// Example On Success function
def printWorkerSuccess(res: Int, c: WorkerContext): Unit = println(s"Successful result was $res. " +
  s"Original arg was ${c.passedArg}")

// Example on failure function
def printWorkerFailure(res: CouldntDoitError, c: WorkerContext): Unit = println(s"Couldn't do it msg: ${res.msg}. " +
  s"Original arg was ${c.passedArg}")

// Running the computation and processing the result 
val exampleComputation = workerFunc(3)
processMyFuncResult(exampleComputation, printWorkerSuccess, printWorkerFailure)
```

A lot here - thanks for the help.

Comment: Try giving the type to the function call: `processMyFuncResult[Int](exampleComputation, printWorkerSuccess, printWorkerFailure)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that if you have a value of

```
trait WorkerFuncResult[T] {
  def result: Either[MyError, T]
  def context: MyFuncContext
}
```

and a function `CouldntDoitError => Something`, it can't handle all errors in result -- it could hold an error that's not a `CouldntDoitError`.

You will need to refine your types if you want to be able to express in your types what you want to handle. In your case, you'll need two extra type parameters:

```
trait WorkerFuncResult[T, E <: MyError, C <: MyFuncContext] {
      def result: Either[E, T]
      def context: C
    }

case class WorkerResult[E <: MyError](result: Either[E, Int], context: WorkerContext) extends WorkerFuncResult[Int, E, WorkerContext]

// Processing function which does the interesting work and returns a WorkerFuncResult
// There are many of these which have specific types which they return (e.g. WorkerResult)
def workerFunc(a: Int): WorkerResult[CouldntDoitError] = {
  val compRes = for {
    res1 <-
      if (a < 10) Left(CouldntDoitError("Less than 10 "))
      else Right(a * 2)
    res2 <-
      if (a < 30) Left(CouldntDoitError("almost made it but didn't"))
      else Right(res1 * 100)
  } yield res2

  WorkerResult(compRes, WorkerContext(a))
}

// Post-processing function - takes a result and invokes an on success function or on failure function
// On the appropriate result or error
def processMyFuncResult[T, E <: MyError, C <: MyFuncContext](
    computationResult: WorkerFuncResult[T, E, C],
    onSuccess: (T, C) => Unit,
    onFailure: (E, C) => Unit
) =
  computationResult.result match {
    case Right(v) => onSuccess(v, computationResult.context)
    case Left(e)  => onFailure(e, computationResult.context)
  }
```